# Sum of data entry with the given index in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum, combinations, python-itertools

I try to get the sum of possible combination of given data in pandas dataframe. To do this I use itertools combination to get all of possible combinations, then by using loop, I sum each of it.

Is there any way to do this without using the loop?

Please check the following script that I created to shows what I want.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

A = pd.Series([50, 20, 75], index = list(range(1, 4)))

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A})

listNew = []
for i in range(1, len(df.A)+1):
    Temp=it.combinations(df.index.values, i)
    for data in Temp:
        listNew.append(data)  

print(listNew)

for data in listNew:
    print(df.A[list(data)].sum())
```

Output of these scripts are:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
50
20
75
70
125
95
145
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, using `reindex`

```
#convert you list of tuple to data frame and using stack to flatten it 
s=pd.DataFrame([(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]).stack().to_frame('index') 

# then we reindex base on the order of it using df.A
s['Value']=df.reindex(s['index']).A.values

#you can using groupby here, but since the index is here, I will recommend sum with level 
s=s.Value.sum(level=0)
s
Out[796]: 
0     50
1     20
2     75
3     70
4    125
5     95
6    145
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```